# Multiple Content Type in single record with multiple user permission

Tags: content-type

I have 2 content types on the same list, Content Type A and Content Type B.

I would like to let user A to fill Content Type A and User B to fill Content Type B on the same record/row.

At the point of anytime, user A can only view/edit Content Type A,
But User B can view/edit Content Type B and view content Type A.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it can't be done as OOTB.

**The alternative solutions**

1. Create two lists for each content type:

   - To Manage content type easily,
   - To Manage record permission easily,
   - Then Create workflow on item added/changed to show the data on the same row,
2. Go ahead with a custom code!
3. Purchase a 3rd party tool like [infowise](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/) that may handle your requirements.